# How to name tags for Android 10?

Tags: discussion, tags

Now that the official name for Android Q has been revealed to be [**Android 10**](https://www.blog.google/products/android/evolving-android-brand/), how are we going to handle the naming of tags specific to that version?

In the past, we've used the version number with the codename (e.g., [4.4-kitkat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.4-kitkat), but that doesn't seem tenable with their abandonment of dessert names. [10-q](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10-q) looks like txtspk for "thank you". To that end, do the old version tags need to be renamed to have a consistent naming convention, or should we just take this as an opportunity to make a break, seeing as how this is a pretty major version?

To me, [android-10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-10) seems the most logical (followed by [android-11](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-11), [android-11.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-11.1), [android-12](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-12), etc.) Do we need "version" in there, though (i.e., [android-version-10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-version-10))?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [android-10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-10) is appropriate with [android-q](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-q) as the synonym. This is also according to what Google uses on [its blog](https://www.blog.google/products/android/evolving-android-brand/).

> Android Q is Android 10

---

About the past Android versions, for naming consistency, I'm thinking of renaming them to [android-version.number-codename](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-version.number-codename), e.g. [android-9-pie](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-9-pie) because it's also what Google uses on their introduction page:

- [Android 9 Pie](https://www.android.com/versions/pie-9-0/)
- [Android 8.0 Oreo](https://www.android.com/versions/oreo-8-0/)
- [Android 7.0 Nougat](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/)
- etc...

However, *this is a low priority* and I'm okay with leaving the current tags as-is because I don't see additional benefits to be gained. (Users will just search for '9' or 'pie' without using 'android' when searching for a tag)

---

Additional remark: there's also [android-one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-one) which follows the "Android [number]" pattern but unrelated to Android versioning at all. However, I don't think there will be a problem since there's no [android-1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-1) (the first version of Android) and its related questions yet.

Comment: Agreed. And I was about to click "Post Your Answer". :)

Comment: @Firelord So you wanted to post Andrews answer? OK, that makes two of us :D